# my post image wont show in the main activity

Tags: java

i have connected my app to firebase, whenever i post an image it stores in firebase storage just fine.
but when i try to retrieve my posted image, it doesn't do that instead just shows my placeholder. no errors

what could be the problem?

```
private void DisplayAllUsersPosts()
{
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                    .setQuery(PostsRef, Posts.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);

            return new PostsViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PostsViewHolder viewHolder, int position, Posts model) {

            //get position of the post on the grid then gets key
            final String PostKey = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
            viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setProfileimage( model.getProfileimage());
            viewHolder.setPostimage(model.getPostimage());

            //ep27
            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent clickPostIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ClickPostActivity.class);
                    clickPostIntent.putExtra("PostKey", PostKey);
                    startActivity(clickPostIntent);
                }
            });

        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    postList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: check your method setProfileimage what is it doing?
Are you getting an image url from the model?
is the image url working?

Comment: @Sergio my profile image displays just fine. I have problem with my postimage. I was thinking there was something wrong with the DisplayAllUsersPosts() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    public PostsViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname)
    {
        TextView username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
        username.setText(fullname);
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage)
    {
        CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_image);
        Picasso.get().load(profileimage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(image);
    }

    public void setTime(String time)
    {
        TextView PostTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
        PostTime.setText("    " + time);
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        TextView PostDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        PostDate.setText("    " + date);
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        TextView PostDescription = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        PostDescription.setText(description);
    }

    public void setPostimage( String postimage)
    {

        ImageView PostImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.get().load(postimage).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderr).into(PostImage);


    }
}
```